# Unable to extract text from website containing a filter

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping, filtered

I'm trying to get all the locations out of the following website (www.mars.com/locations) using Python, with Requests and BeautifulSoup.

The website has a filter to select continent, country and region, so that it will display only the locations the company has in the selected area. They also include their headquarters at the bottom of the page, and this information is always there regardless of the filter applied.

I have no problem extracting the data for the headquarters using the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mars.com/locations'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

HQ = soup.find('div', class_='global-headquarter pr-5 pl-3').text.strip()

print(HQ)
```

The output of the code is:

> Mars, Incorporated (Global Headquarters)
>   6885 Elm Street
>   McLean
>   Virginia
>   22101
>   +1(703) 821-4900

I want to do the same for all other locations, but I'm struggling to extract the data using the same approach (adjusting the path, of course). I've tried everything and I'm out of ideas. Would really appreciate someone giving me a hand or at least pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The info you are trying to scrape is loaded via JavaScript.  You would need to load the page in a headless browser, simulate clicks, and then scrape.  However it would be easier for you to grab the info out of the  `<div class="location-container" data-location="...">`  tag.  It appears to be html encoded JSON. Should be much easier to parse.

Comment: I was thinking that could be the issue but I don't know how to use json. One of the answers below helped me get started so I can take it from there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

All location data can be retrieved in text format. Decomposing this into a string is one way to do it. I'm not an expert in this field, so I can't help you any more.

```
content_json = soup.find('div', class_='location-container')
data = content_json['data-location']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That moves me in the right direction so it's been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not an expert in BeautifulSoup, so i'll use [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-css-selectors-in-multi-root-documents) to get the data. all the locations are embedded in a `location-container` css class, with a `data-location` attribute.

```
import requests
from parsel import Selector
response = requests.get(url).text
selector = Selector(text=response)
data = selector.css(".location-container").xpath("./@data-location").getall()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not tied to BeautifulSoup, just use it because I know it better. Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Can't believe it was that easy after all...